# mule and rest with post method type

Tags: java, web-services, rest, mule

```
@Path("/")
public class RestIntegration {
    @GET
    @Path("get/{id1}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getOperation(@PathParam("id1")String id){
        System.out.println("GET: Id from UI-->"+id);
        return "Your Id is-->"+id;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post/{id1}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postOperation(@PathParam("id1")String id){
        System.out.println("----INSIDE POST operation----"+id);
        return Response.ok("Response from Mule Rest component").build();
    }
}
```

Muleflow:

```
 <flow name="restintegrationFlow1" doc:name="restintegrationFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="restint" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
            <component class="com.net.rest.RestIntegration"/>
        </jersey:resources>
    </flow>
```

It works fine with get method. `http://localhost:8081/restint/get/10`.

When I pass `http://localhost:8081/restint/post/22`, select post type and click send gives following error:

```
ERROR 2014-07-31 11:18:43,337 [[restintegration].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to create MuleMessage
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-64
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. String index out of range: -1 (java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException)
  java.lang.String:1871 (null)
2. Failed to create MuleMessage (org.mule.api.lifecycle.CreateException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractTransportMessageHandler:462 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/lifecycle/CreateException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1871)
    at org.mule.transport.http.multipart.MultiPartInputStream.parse(MultiPartInputStream.java:349)
    at org.mule.transport.http.multipart.MultiPartInputStream.getParts(MultiPartInputStream.java:304)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I use chrome rest client to invoke the url. In rest client I didnot pass any values in header or paload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, in google chrome rest client, i didnot select content type in the header.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" basePath="restint"/>
```

http://localhost:8081/restint/post/22
it is working for me -----INSIDE POST operation----22-
Response from Mule Rest component

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?